# Http Post with NSData initWithContentsOfURL

Tags: iphone, objective-c, http, networking, post

I want to do a HTTP post, updating some information to the server

The URL might be "http://www.aaa.com/aaa.aspx?name=John&pw=123&age=25"

And I think this method should work:

```
NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:[urlString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
NSData* returnData = [NSData initWithContentsOfURL: url];
[NSString* strRet = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8String];
```

So how could know the update is sucessful? What would be in the NSData returned?

@"200" or some other string returned by the server, such as @"YES"?

Thanks

Comment: I guess that will depend on server implentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your request would end up being a GET request.   And the data returned would be whatever data the web site returns for that URL, not the http headers.    I recommend using the excellent ASIHTTPRequest library: http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/ for communicating with web sites, determining POST/GET mode, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSString *str = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
```

and have a look into `error` to check if the request was successfully.

For bigger requests, please check this link:
[Objective-C: server requests in a thread (like AsyncTask in Android)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4269842/509535)